# Too much time consumed to retrieve data from server

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, android-asynctask

I am developing an app that retrieves data from a php server. I am receiving a json array from the php server. When I run apk in android emulator, it works perfectly, but the problem occurs when I run this apk on real android phone. It takes too much time to retrieve data. I have searched a lot of resources, but I am unable to solve this problem. Please any one give me some hints to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

CostForSecretCloseMem class

```
public class CostForSecretCloseMem extends AppCompatActivity
{

        private ListView listView;
        private RelativeLayout emptyView;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.costs_layout);
                initComponent();
        }

        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        private void initComponent()
        {
                emptyView = findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
                SharedPreferenceData sharedPreferenceData = new SharedPreferenceData(this);
                CheckInternetIsOn internetIsOn = new CheckInternetIsOn(this);
                listView = findViewById(R.id.list);
                if(internetIsOn.isOnline())
                {
                        try {
                                String DATA = URLEncoder.encode("userName", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(sharedPreferenceData.getCurrentUserName(), "UTF-8");
                                //importantData.getAllShoppingCost(getResources().getString(R.string.shoppingCost), DATA,infoInterfaces);
                                TestBackground testBackground = new TestBackground(this);
                                testBackground.setOnResultListener(infoInterfaces);
                                testBackground.execute(getResources().getString(R.string.shoppingCost),DATA);
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                }
        }

        //process shopping only_show_cost json data
        private void processJsonData(String result)
        {
                List<CostModel> costList = new ArrayList<>();
                int count=0;
                String name,taka,date,id;
                try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.optJSONArray("costList");

                        while (count<jsonArray.length())
                        {
                                JSONObject jObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
                                id = jObject.getString("id");
                                name = jObject.getString("name");
                                taka = jObject.getString("taka");
                                date = jObject.getString("date");

                                costList.add(new CostModel(id,name,taka,date,""));
                                count++;
                        }

                        if(costList.isEmpty())
                                listView.setEmptyView(emptyView);
                        else
                                emptyView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                        CostAdapter adapter = new CostAdapter(this, costList);
                        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

        //get all shopping list
        OnAsyncTask infoInterfaces = new OnAsyncTask() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(final String result) {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                        if(result!=null)
                                                processJsonData(result);
                                }
                        });
                }
        };
}
```

AsyncTask

```
public class TestBackground extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
{
     private Context context;
     private OnAsyncTask onAsyncTaskInterface;

     public TestBackground(Context context)
     {
          this.context = context;
     }


     //success result
     public void setOnResultListener(OnAsyncTask onAsyncResult) {
          if (onAsyncResult != null) {
               this.onAsyncTaskInterface = onAsyncResult;
          }
     }

     @Override
     public String doInBackground(String... params) {

          String result = "";
          String fileName = params[0];
          String postData = params[1];

          try {
               URL url = new URL(fileName);
               HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
               httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
               OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
               OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8");
               BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(outputStreamWriter);

               bufferedWriter.write(postData);
               bufferedWriter.flush();
               bufferedWriter.close();
               outputStream.close();
               InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
               BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));

               String line;

               while ((line= bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
                    result = line;

               bufferedReader.close();
               inputStream.close();
               httpURLConnection.disconnect();
               onAsyncTaskInterface.onSuccess(result);

          } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
          }catch (Exception e)
          {
               e.printStackTrace();
          }
          return result.toString();
     }


      public interface OnAsyncTask {
                void onSuccess(String message);
        }
}
```

php code

```
<?php

    require"connection.php";
    require"getSession.php";

    $userName = $_POST["userName"];
    $session = new Sessions();
    $month = $session->session($userName);

    $sql = "SELECT GroupID FROM member_info WHERE UserName LIKE '$userName';";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

    if($result->num_rows>0)
    {
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            if($row["GroupID"]!="Null")
                getCostList($row["GroupID"],$month);
        }
    }

    function getCostList($value,$month)
    {
        require"connection.php";
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM cost WHERE groupName LIKE '$value' and cMonth LIKE '$month';";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

        $response = array();

        if($result->num_rows>0)
        {
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                array_push($response,array("id"=>$row[0],"name"=>$row[1],"taka"=>$row[4],"date"=>$row[5]));

            echo json_encode(array("costList"=>$response));
        }
    }

    $conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Using wifi or mobile connection? Where is your server running? And you could give figures!

Comment: `onAsyncTaskInterface.onSuccess(result);` Normally one would call the interface in onPostExecute(). And then you could get rid of runOnUiThread().

Comment: I also did this ,but same problem occurs...

Comment: I highly recommend to work with Volley or Retrofit instead using directly HttpUrlConnection that way you minimize your code and you get rid of AsyncTask it will improve dramatically the speed. I used to do the same as you and the moment I switched to volley the http requests became much much faster.

Comment: Is it the PHP script that is taking too long to return something or is it the connection that's slow?

Comment: try to implement using volley , retrofit or okhttp library ..

Answer (score 0):

You have done many mistake in your code.

1. Using SELECT * was not good advise to get the data, You know what are all the data needed so be specific which selecting the data (id,name,taka,date)).
2. Using while loop after selected from the query you should use fetch all and return data as it is.
3. Use JOIN query to get the data in single query.

If you do above method it will be significantly fast.

```
 require"connection.php";
```

Above line used two times it is wrong instead use global variable to get DB connection inside function.

Comment: Is their your data size is big or its quite normal?